# How do I search for questions that include tag X, but exclude tag Y?

Tags: support, search, tag-search

I want to find questions that include a certain tag but exclude a separate, different tag.

For example, suppose I wanted to find and read all questions that include a javascript tag, but I don't even want to see any question from that set that includes a jquery tag.

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the `-` sign:

`[javascript] -[jquery]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this was exactly what I was looking for.  Seems so obvious now that I see the answer :p